# Kubernetes Ingress Setup

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-ingress

I tried to setup a Kubernetes Ingress to route external http traffic towards a frontend pod (with path /) and backend pod (with path /rest/*), but I alway get a 400 error instead of the main nginx index.html.

So I tried the Google Kubernetes example at page https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/http-balancer, but I get always a 400 error. Any idea?

Following is the deployment descriptor for the frontend "cup-fe" (running nginx with angular app):

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: cup-fe
  namespace: default
  labels:
    app: cup-fe
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: "cup-fe"
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: "cup-fe"
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: "eu.gcr.io/gpi-cup-242708/cup-fe:latest"
        name: "cup-fe"
```

Next the service NodePort:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: cup-fe
  namespace: default
spec:
  ports:
  - name: http
    port: 80
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 80
  selector:
    run: cup-fe
  type: NodePort
```

And last, but not least, the Ingress to expose the frontend outside:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: http-ingress
spec:
  rules:
  - host: cup-fe
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: cup-fe
          servicePort: 80
      - path: /rest/*
        backend:
          serviceName: cup-be
          servicePort: 8080
```

I left behind "cup-be" deployment descriptor (running wildfly), because is pretty similar to the "cup-fe" one. Please note also that if I create a LoadBalancer service instead of NodePort, I can reach the web page but I have some CORS problems to call the backend.

Comment: it's hard to tell without YAML manifests. Please post your manifests here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you have used wrong [selector](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/field-selectors/) `run: cup-fe` entire particular service configuration. Since I have replaced label with `app: cup-fe` in `cup-fe` service configuration the relevant Pod [endpoints](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#services-without-selectors) showed up and I've received successful responses as well.

```
$ kubectl get ep | grep cup-fe|awk '{print $2}'
<IP_address>:80,<IP_address>:80
```

If the issue still persists just let me know and push a comment below my answer.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I didn't understand completely, I tried to replace app:cup-fe label in the deployment descriptor with app:fe,but it doesn't work

Comment: You have used different selector in the service `run: cup-fe` which does not match any labels in deployment configuration(`app: cup-fe`).

Comment: Just replace `run: cup-fe` with `app: cup-fe` in the service and that's it.

Comment: If you find my answer helpful and the issue no longer exists, please accept the answer.